# How can I create gallery of array images with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that generates and stores an image, but I would like to create a gallery that shows all images that have been stored.

I need help in creating the 'for loop' to loop through the array and output each image that has been stored.

https://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/XWYLwbq

```
     let newData = {
        img: img.src
         },
        data = (sessionStorage.getItem("data")) ? JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("data")) : []
  
     // Update data
        data = [...data, newData]
  
     // Save data
        sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data))
  
        let i = 1;
          for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          document.write(`<img src="${img.src}" class="xxx"/>`);
          }

       }
```

The 'for loop' keep printing the same image repeatedly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; your `document.write` refers to `img`. Wouldn't you want to use the images from `data`?

Comment: I'm in a mess and need any help available. I am just trying to output the array results [images] to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in ligne 55 and 56

```
 document.write(`<img src="${img.src}" class="xxx"/>`);
```

you overwrite all your html and replace with images stocked in data
something like this ...

```
<html><head></head><body><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668800477238-0c701ec52be9?crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=jpg&amp;ixid=MnwzOTE3Mzd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzE2NDA5MTk&amp;ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;q=80&amp;w=1080" class="xxx"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668800477238-0c701ec52be9?crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=jpg&amp;ixid=MnwzOTE3Mzd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzE2NDA5MTk&amp;ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;q=80&amp;w=1080" class="xxx"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668800477238-0c701ec52be9?crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;fit=max&amp;fm=jpg&amp;ixid=MnwzOTE3Mzd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzE2NDA5MTk&amp;ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;q=80&amp;w=1080" class="xxx"></body></html>
```

i dont know if it's  that what you want or no ,but well if you want to fixe that you can use `document.body.appendChild` instead of `document.write`

the seconde problem is in

```
src="${img.src}"
```

to get the right sources of the images you should do

```
src="${data[i].img}"
```